# i was installing cloudstack and ended up in this error can anyone help me?

Tags: cloud

i was trying to install cloudstack and while installing cloudstack management mysql server this error was showed up`

```
apt-get install cloudstack-management mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1).
cloudstack-management is already the newest version (4.18.1.0-shapeblue1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 158948
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

ive tried this

```
root@stack:~# sudo apt —fix-broken install
E: Invalid operation —fix-broken
root@stack:~# sudo apt install —reinstall ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package —reinstall
root@stack:~# sudo apt-get install —no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package —no-install-recommends
```

and it shows error again

i juz wanted to install and run cloudstack within 5 days ...someone please help me